# populate NSMutableArray using the CoreData database

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchrequest

Im trying to populate an NSMutableArray from the CoreData database (using swift) but not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
var stuff: NSMutableArray = []
```

populating the NSMutableArray:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let freq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyData")       
    stuff = context.executeFetchRequest(freq, error: nil)

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define `stuff` as

```
var stuff : Array<AnyObject> = []
```

Which will create `stuff` as an array suitable for the return type of `executeFetchRequest()`.

When you then access elements of the array you will also need to satisfy the type constraints.  You should look into the Apple documentation for `as`, `as?` and `is` and the associated usage examples.  In the very simplest case it would be something like:

```
var aThing : NSManagedObject? = stuff[0] as? NSManagedObject
```

For the above `aThing` would be `nil` if `stuff[0]` is not an `NSManagedObject` nor subclasses.

Comment: How would I write stuff.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) with this type?

Comment: `objectAtIndex()` will return entities from your CoreData model.  I believe they will be instances of NSManagedObject (or your subclasses).  See edit to above answer.

Comment: Yes, you can use `array[index]` instead of `objectAtIndex()`